# VBA, Clearing Contents of a Selected Row from Column A to J

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a macro that will clear contents of a selected row but only from columns A to J, I can clear the entire row but that is not very useful as I have multiple tables on that row.

Please Help

Thank You!

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Worksheet.Columns("A:J")).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

**One row:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim RowNo As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        RowNo = Selection.Row '<- Get row number

        .Range("A" & RowNo & ":J" & RowNo).ClearContents '<- Clear range A to J of the selected line

    End With

End Sub
```

**Multiple rows:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        For Each rng In Selection.Rows
            .Range("A" & rng.Row & ":J" & rng.Row).ClearContents
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What if several rows are selected at once?

Comment: Variable *RowNo* get only the number of the first row. If you want to avoid that you may use intersect and target.count=1.

Comment: Yes. that s the OP asked. Clear selected row.

Comment: @GSerg i have at another pieces which can be used to clear multiple rows. Could you please evaluate?

Comment: Your code clears the range on `Sheet1` that has the same location and shape as the selected range (which may be on a different sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can run over every cell in your selectin, and clear its contents:

```
Sub test()
  Dim R As Range
  For Each R In Selection:
    If R.Column <= 10 Then
    R.ClearContents
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

The `Column` being smaller than 10 means being somewhere from column `A` to `J`.